# Help sending bitcoin to bitcoincash wallet

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

I've used an UPHOLD wallet to buy an AntMiner S9 from www.bitmain.com.

Bitmain provided a bitcoin cash address for payment.  However, by mistake, I sent bitcoin worth $1450 USD to their *bitcoin cash* wallet. Now, they have not confirmed the payment. And now I do not know what to do?  Where is my money?

Uphold gave me a BlockChain confirmation address and the transfer appears but as (not spent).  Neither bitmain.com nor Uphold has given me any reply.

I did this on Friday, November 17 and today, Monday, November 20, I have not received a response.

What should I do?  Can someone help me? I cannot afford to lose $1450 USD.

Answer (score 0):

If you control both the sending (BTC) and receiving (BCC) wallets, you can recover the money by restoring the private key from the BCC wallet into a new wallet created on the BTC BlockChain.  Unfortunately, in this case it appears you have sent money to a BitCoin Cash wallet you do not control.

If you do *not* control the receiving address, sending a Bitcoin payment to a Bitcoin Cash address will almost certainly result in total loss of the money sent to the Bitcoin Cash address.  When you send Bitcoin, you are sending it to another address on the **Bitcoin** BlockChain.  There is no built-in method of sending Bitcoin to Bitcoin Cash directly; you should convert the Bitcoin into currency, then purchase Bitcoin Cash with that currency, typically through an exchange.

If you do *not* own the receiving wallet, the only way to get that money back would be in the highly unlikely event you sent it to an address that happens to exist in the Bitcoin BlockChain, and the person who owns that Bitcoin address decides to be nice, and send the money back to you.

As always, it pays to understand how a currency works by using a small amount of money at first.  You wouldn't give your 4 year old $1,500 to play with, would you?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. The money in bitcoin was sent to a wallet of the company bitmain.com and this was to buy an antminer s9, I got it in a page that gives me uphold.com to confirm my transfer in blockchain which are these:                                                                                       
 ID DE LA TRANSACCIÓN EN RESERVECHAIN

ed6fdc73-796d-48a7-881f-b8307188594f
Transacción llevada a cabo utilizando Uphold Android Wallet
ción?
View sources
BLOCKCHAIN TRANSACTION ID

322855dabca7f30e3389d5a1f22426cc06c68c6dfe7bc8b4ecd27b30e817f2d2
But I do not understand.